# Is there a way to toggle visibility in one line of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, animation, coffeescript, gsap

Is there a way in javascript/coffeescript to dynamically toggle visibility based on the object whenever opacity enters or exits 0?

To improve performance with lots of hidden objects, and to be confident that if I previously hid something, it won’t interfere with my currently visible objects, I frequently find myself adding lines of code around my opacity instructions that toggles the visibility of an object, or when animating opacity to 0, adding an event listener that follows opacity animation.

Essentially how do I do this: allthethings: if opacity == 0 make @.visible = false else @.visible = true

Comment: How about `@.visible = opacity != 0`?

Comment: Thanks, forgot about that